# I would like to be able to import and combine specific functions from a range of different files into one file

Tags: python, pyqt

Using command and pyuic, I was able to turn several .ui files created in PYQT Designer into pythonic .py files. However, I would like to be able to pull specific functions from these files to be displayed in a much bigger Window.

[image]

This is the code I was able to create. However, it just opens two windows. This is not what I want happening. I want to be able to take what's in each of these windows and combine them together, like in the picture above.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys, time
from mainwindow_compranges import CompRanges
from mainwindow_createmodels import CreateModels
from mainwindow_files import Files
from mainwindow_normalization import Normalization
from mainwindow_setup import  SetUp

class createModel(QMainWindow, CompRanges):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

class files(QMainWindow, Files):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
c = createModel()
f = files()
f.show()
c.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen? You imported some classes (or functions), but never use them.

Comment: I haven't used them because I don't have a solution, but i still wanted to showcase an attempt. I'm just not sure how to do this.